# How to extend NextPage type to add custom field to page component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to follow the next-auth [documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client) using TypeScript. Using the following code and some code in `_app.tsx` from the docs I can protect a page:

```ts
AdminDashboard.auth = {
  role: "admin",
  loading: <AdminLoadingSkeleton />,
  unauthorized: "/login-with-different-user", // redirect to this url
}
```

**What is the right way to implement this using TypeScript?**

I found a solution which works, but I am not sure if this is the right way:

```ts
export type NextPageWithAuth = NextPage & {
  auth: boolean,
  role: string
}

type NextPageAuthProps = {
  Component: NextPageWithAuth,
  pageProps: any
}
```

The `AppProps` type is quite more sophisticated than my own `NextPageAuthProps`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the page, you can extend the built-in `NextPage` type to include the `auth` field with the appropriate type.

```js
import type { NextPage } from 'next';

type PageAuth = {
  role: string
  loading: JSX.Element
  unauthorized: string
};

export type NextPageWithAuth<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
  auth: PageAuth
};

const AdminDashboard: NextPageWithAuth = () => {
  // Your `AdminDashboard` code here
};

AdminDashboard.auth = {
  role: "admin",
  loading: <AdminLoadingSkeleton />,
  unauthorized: "/login-with-different-user"
};

export default AdminDashboard;
```

Then, in the custom `_app`, you can extend `AppProps` so that the `Component` prop extends the type you declared in the page.

```js
import type { NextComponentType, NextPageContext } from 'next';
import type { NextPageWithAuth } from '<path-to>/AdminDashboard';

type NextComponentWithAuth = NextComponentType<NextPageContext, any, {}> & Partial<NextPageWithAuth>

type ExtendedAppProps<P = {}> = AppProps<P> & {
  Component: NextComponentWithAuth
};

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: ExtendedAppProps) {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the return statement that satisfies the type `NextPageWithAuth`.

Comment: @petrosmm It's extending the existing `NextPage` type to also include an `auth` property.

Comment: That part is clear, but, what would a sample return line look like for `AdminDashboard` ?

Comment: @petrosmm That would be like any other React component. The additional typing just allows to then have `AdminDashboard.auth = { ... }` set on that component, without TypeScript complaining.

Comment: Oh wow, worked, thank you. That was so simple -- still learning here. It seemed like an object initializer usage that maybe I was not familiar with. Upvote!

Comment: Is there not a way to do this by extending the types in a types.d.ts with a module? I feel like there should be, but I don't know enough to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer's type definitions hurt my head, so I solved the issue by calling `getStaticProps` with an `auth` property on the pages I wanted to protect:

```
// bottom of page I want to protect..

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  return {
    props: { auth: true },
  };
};
```

and then consuming the prop in _app.tsx like so:

```
const MyApp: AppType<{ session: Session | null, auth: boolean }> = ({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) => {

  const { auth } = pageProps

  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session} refetchOnWindowFocus={false}>
      <NavBar />
      {auth ? (
        <RouteGuard>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </RouteGuard>
      ) : (
        <Component {...pageProps} />  
      )}
      <ReactQueryDevtools />
      <MobileFooter />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
};
```